# How can I read Google BigQuery View data in Databricks/Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery

How can I read Google BigQuery view data in spark? I am able to read data from Google BigQuery tables using Service Account Authentication by using below query

```
df = (spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile",credentialfilepath)
      .option("parentProject",projectName)
      .option("table",ViewName)
      .load())
```

But I am not able to read view data by using this, also I have applies other options as well like `.option("viewsEnabled", "true")` and `.option("materializationDataset","dataplatform")` but It is giving the error:

> com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException:
> Access Denied: Project projectname: User does not have
> bigquery.jobs.create permission in project projectname

Can anyone suggest the way to read view data?

Comment: What "Role" did you assign to the service account that you use for authentication? Just to confirm did you install "spark-bigquery-connector"?

Comment: @RiccoD, These are the roles that I have assigned to Service Account BigQuery Data editor, BigQuery Job User, BigQuery DataViewer, BigQuery ReadSession User.
Apart from this , I am using the service account Key json files for authentication

Comment: I tried creating a new service account with the permissions you have given, including "Storage Object Admin" and used the code you have provided above. I was able to query an existing view in my project. Can you  double check if you are using the correct credential file on your code?

Comment: Thanks, @RiccoD, Now I am able to fetch the View data as well by giving the proper access control to the service account

Answer (score 0):

Providing the proper roles for the service account used for authentication solved the problem. See steps below on adding the roles to the service account used for authentication:

1. Open Google Cloud Console
2. Go to IAM & Admin > IAM. Look for the service account to be used.
3. When a service account is identified, click the edit button (pencil icon) at the right side.
4. Click "+ Add Another Role" and add the following roles

   - BigQuery Data editor
   - BigQuery Job User
   - BigQuery Data Viewer
   - BigQuery Read Session User
   - Storage Object Admin

   [image]
5. Click Save
6. Run the spark code provided in the question

Comment: Hi @Ricco D , is it possible to mount BigQuery table to databricks so that Autoloader can pump data to Silver tables or Bronze tables?